# UICollectionViewController in navigation stack not being deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I've got a UICollectionViewController that comes off of the root view controller in a navigation stack. When I enter the CollectionViewController, everything is fine - but when I tap back, the memory level stays the same. I don't know what's causing it to be retained.

```
import UIKit

class ImagesViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

var user = User()
var images: [UIImage] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        images.append(UIImage(named: "test.png")!)
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        let filePath: NSString = NSString(string: "https://www.example.com/uploads/\(user.username)/\(i).png")

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: .defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: filePath)!)

        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UIImageView
    imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    images.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: NSURLSessionDelegte

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {

    var image: UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!)!

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.images.append(image)
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    })
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect I know the problem, but can you be specific on which part of your code, or what method you're using to segue back into the other controller?

Comment: You should try to check your rootviewcontroller part but not CollectionViewController.

Comment: Did you try adding "dealloc" function and breakpoint in it to see if it hits?

Comment: @KelvinLau I'm not using any specific method, just the default UINavigationBar back button.

Comment: I think it'll be ok as long as memory doesn't increase when you segue back and forth. In my experience, none of my UIViewController based controllers call deinit. Perhaps something holds them all together and it's intended that way. 

At first I thought you were having the problem of stacking your navi stack up.

Comment: @KelvinLau It basically is increasing as I see back and forth. The level stays constant as you segue back, but as you go in, it'll increase by about 30 MB. It also increases as I **delete** items from the collection view, which bewilders me the most.

Comment: @jkaufman Based on the symptoms, I'd say somethings up with your images array. Can you remove the initialization from viewDidLoad and use a lazy initializer instead (for the array of UIImages)? I'd love to know how you solved it, if you do.